# Unable to specialize a member function template with boost::enable_if in VS .NET 2008

Tags: c++, templates, boost, sfinae, enable-if

I'm trying to specialize a member function template for two different types of classes as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/utility/enable_if.hpp>

struct Wibble
{
    static const bool CAN_WIBBLE = true;
};

struct Wobble
{
    static const bool CAN_WIBBLE = false;
};

struct Foo
{
    //template<typename T>   // Why isn't this declaration sufficient?
    //void doStuff();

    template<typename T>
    typename boost::enable_if_c<T::CAN_WIBBLE,void>::type
    doStuff();

    template<typename T>
    typename boost::enable_if_c<!T::CAN_WIBBLE,void>::type
    doStuff();  
};

template<typename T>
typename boost::enable_if_c<T::CAN_WIBBLE,void>::type
Foo::doStuff()
{
    std::cout << "wibble ..." << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
typename boost::enable_if_c<!T::CAN_WIBBLE,void>::type
Foo::doStuff()
{
    std::cout << "I can't wibble ..." << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    f.doStuff<Wibble>();
    f.doStuff<Wobble>();
}
```

Whereas GCC 4.8.2 compiles the code, VS .NET 2008 spits out the error message:

```
error C2244: 'Foo::doStuff' : unable to match function definition to an existing declaration

        definition
        'boost::enable_if_c<!T::CAN_WIBBLE,void>::type Foo::doStuff(void)'
        existing declarations
        'boost::enable_if_c<!T::CAN_WIBBLE,void>::type Foo::doStuff(void)'
        'boost::enable_if_c<T::CAN_WIBBLE,void>::type Foo::doStuff(void)'
```

Comment: I would write it off as inability of the MSVC++ logic to deal with function overloads with no arguments and explicitly specified parameters (and I vaguely recall having some problem with remotely related case too). I would only use overloaded function templates when I want the parameter deduction; tag dispatch as suggested by Jarod42 is the preferred approach here.

Comment: Does gcc compile it in strict C++98 mode (`-std=c++98`)? The rules were relaxed somewhat in C++11 and MSVC++ 15.0 (MSVS 9.0 (2008)) is not C++11.

Comment: @Jan, I'm not using C++11. Also VS compiles the methods if they are inlined.

Comment: I know you are not using C++11, but I am not sure gcc is not accepting something that was not permitted in C++98 in the default mode. That's why I am asking about the strict mode.

Comment: @Jan the code compiles in gcc 4.8.2 with the strict C++98 flag, `-std=c++98`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to use tag dispatching: https://ideone.com/PA5PTg

```
struct Foo
{
    template<bool wibble>
    void _doStuff();

public:
    template<typename T>
    void doStuff()
    {
        _doStuff<T::CAN_WIBBLE>();
    }
};

template<>
void Foo::_doStuff<true>() { std::cout << "wibble ..." << std::endl; }

template<>
void Foo::_doStuff<false>() { std::cout << "I can't wibble ..." << std::endl; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't partially specialize (member) function templates. End of story.

Even if you could, you should have had a SFINAE-friendly primary template. In pseudo code:

```
template<typename T, typename Enable> void doStuff();
template<typename T> void doStuff<T, typename boost::enable_if_c<T::CAN_WIBBLE,void>::type>()
    { std::cout << "wibble ..." << std::endl; }
template<typename T> void doStuff<T, typename boost::enable_if_c<!T::CAN_WIBBLE,void>::type>()
    { std::cout << "I can't wibble ..." << std::endl; }
```

You could still use this technique if you are ready class templates (as functors or just types defining non-template methods...).

As a rule of thumb, for *function templates*, overload resolution provides static polymorphism that removes the need for partial specialization. See

- [GotW #49 Template Specialization and Overloading](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/049.htm)
- [Why Not Specialize Function Templates?](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm)

Both by Herb Sutter

Comment: That's why the commented-out declaration is not sufficient. But the question is not trying to specialize function templates. It is trying to define two different function template overloads.

Comment: @JanHudec I agree. The OP's code was simply not correct. But _clearly_ he was looking for the correct incantation for the specialization (see the commented primary template **and** the question title). And my answer explains that there isn't a correct form, what it would have looked like, why he couldn't get it to work, and what he can instead.

Comment: As far as I can tell it is _only_ the commented out part that is incorrect, but the code as written is actually _correct_ (but the compiler is lacking).

Comment: @JanHudec I assumed he had changed the code around until the compiler would accept it. Admittedly, I didn't pay attention to the MSVC error messages (I never do, they are frequently not very informative...). Cheers